# Getting Error while Spring Boot Application Deployment Using Jenkins CI & CD spring boot application deployment in tomcat, Any Solution would be nice

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins

I have a spring boot application CI/CD pipeline create but it is failing. Git, Jenkins, Tomcat and Maven have errors while Spring Boot Application Deployment Using Jenkins CI & CD spring boot application deployment in tomcat. Any solution would be nice.

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Clean". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDnFu.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in Jenkins' maven job configuration. It should be `clean` instead of `Clean`. All lower case.